# Selecting specific column tags to display from a set of rows using BeautifulSoup and Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a table that retrieves that most recent n injuries from the CBS NFL injuries page, just to add an aesthetic to a project. I have no problem scraping the data and separating it into rows or individual columns, but I've spent 2 full days trying to find answers and fix this, but I need to move onward. What I am seeing:

[image: Current Output]

I would like to see (for each row):

**ARI  Budda Baker  SS  Ankle**
**ARI  Markus Golden  OLB  Illness**
etc.

My current python app.py code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"), strict_slashes=False)
def index():
   # Parsing Code will go here
   if request.method == "POST":
      try:
         global url, specific_element

         url = "https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/injuries/daily"

         only_tr = SoupStrainer('tr')
         source = requests.get(url).text
         soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml', parse_only=only_tr)
         specific_element = soup.find_all('tr', limit=16)[1:]
 

         return render_template("index.html",
                                results=specific_element
                                )

      except Exception as e:
         flash(e, 'danger')

   return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

My HTML:

```
        <div class="w3-third">
            <div class="w3-card-4 w3-container" style="min-height:500px">               
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h3>15 Most Recent NFL Injuries</h3>
                            <div class="bg-white shadow p-4 rounded results">
                                {% if results %}
                                {% for result in results %}
                                <p> {{ result | striptags }} </p>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've tried to separate the individual values to create a dataframe using each column in a dict, as such:

```
 # Scrape CBS NFL Daily Injuries
    executable_path = {'executable_path': ChromeDriverManager().install()}
    browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path, headless=True)

    # Visit the webpage
    url = "https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/injuries/daily"
    browser.visit(url)

    # Convert the browser html to a soup object
    html = browser.html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    # Create empty lists
    player = []
    position = []
    injury = []
    team = []
    logo = []

    # Add try/except for error handling
    try:
        specific_element = soup.select('tr.TableBase-bodyTr')
        # Find all of the Tr rows
        rows = soup.findAll('tr', limit=21)[1:]  # the 0th tr is headers

    except AttributeError:
        return None, None


    # Get info from each row
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        player.append(specific_element[i].find(
            'span', class_='CellPlayerName--long').get_text())
        position.append(specific_element[i].find(
            'td', class_='TableBase-bodyTd').next_sibling.next_sibling.get_text().strip())
        injury.append(specific_element[i].find(
            'td', class_='TableBase-bodyTd').next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.get_text().strip())
        team.append(specific_element[i].find('span', class_='TeamName').get_text())
        logo.append(specific_element[i].find('img', class_='TeamLogo-image').get('src'))

    recent_injuries = pd.DataFrame({
        'Team': team,
        'Player': player,
        'Position': position,
        'Injury': injury
    })

    return recent_injuries.to_html(classes="table table-hover")
```

This returned a dataframe with the correct values in jupyter, but when I tried to place the dataframe into the HTML table, it formatted it with a lot of brackets.

I also tried using find_all('td'), which does return all of the correct information, but separates each by row. I wanted to use the 'tr' because all of the information is there, but I don't know how to remove the lines I don't want, and to separate the values that I do.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the doubling of the name was a dynamic change with the webpage size providing a shortened name with small size and longer name when larger, but they were under the same tag in ('td')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxX1f.png). By specifically calling the 'span' with class_='CellPlayerName--long', I was able to only extract the longer version of the name. The updated working code follows:

**Flask:**

```
    @app.route("/",  methods=("GET", "POST"), strict_slashes=False)
def index():

   url = "https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/injuries/daily"
   source = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')

   data = soup.find('tr')
   table_data = []
   trs = soup.select('tr.TableBase-bodyTr')
   

   for tr in trs[1:16]:
      row = []
      row.extend([tr.select('td')[0].text])
      row.extend([tr.find('span', class_='CellPlayerName--long').text])
      row.extend([tr.select('td')[2].text])
      row.extend([tr.select('td')[3].text])

      table_data.append(row)

   data = table_data


   return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="w3-third">
                <div class="w3-card-4 w3-container" style="min-height:500px;width:97%">               
                    <div class="w3-col s4">
                        <h3 class="text-nowrap">15 Most Recent Injuries</h3>
                        <table class="table table-striped text-nowrap">
                            <thead class="table-header">
                                <th scope="col">Team</th>
                                <th scope="col">Player</th>
                                <th scope="col">Position</th>
                                <th scope="col">Injury</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for element in data %}
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="font-weight-light" scope="col">{{element[0]}}</th>
                                    <th class="font-weight-light" scope="col">{{element[1]}}</th>
                                    <th class="font-weight-light" scope="col">{{element[2]}}</th>
                                    <th class="font-weight-light" scope="col">{{element[3]}}</th>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS** All CSS here is from w3, so no code needs to be added to style.css file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

The updated table:

[image: Web Scrape of CBS NFL Daily Injuries]